# Marker events for MapQuest

Tags: javascript, mapquest

I need to be able to register event callbacks to marker drag events so that I can run reverselookup and get the address at the end of `dragend`. Also while dragging I need to show "dragging" as text in a debug window. In google map api's this is possible, but in `mapquest` icon api's I have not been able to find the documentation.

I tried this,

```
marker.on('dragend', function(e) {
    popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).openOn(this);
    reverseLookup(e.latlng, generatePopupContent);
});
```

`e.latlng` returns undefined.

But if I use the same for map object

```
map.on('click', function(f) { 
    popup.setLatLng(f.latlng).openOn(this);
    reverseLookup(f.latlng, generatePopupContent);
});
```

`f.latlng` returns a properly formatted latlng

I checked
https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/javascript-api/events/#poi_...

but how do I get the same event registered for a marker.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it in a quick test.

```
marker = L.marker([45, -120], {
    draggable: true
})
.addTo(map)
.on('dragend', function(e){
    console.log(e.target._latlng);
});
```

Comment: I'll try this and report back